# preg_replace unless URL unless in quotes

Tags: php

i have a string like this:

```
$str = 'hi, http://www.google.com is a search engine while "http://www.facebook.com" is a social network';
```

I would like to convert http://www.google.com to a link and NOT convert http://www.facebook.com (because it is in quotes). Here's what i have already

```
$return = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $return);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is you solution

```
<?php
$str = 'hi, http://www.google.com is a search engine while "http://www.facebook.com" is a social network';
$s=explode(",",$str);
$s[1];
$n=explode(" ",$s[1]);
echo $n[1];
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, the string could be anything and may or may not include a comma. $str could be "hello hello hello"